# How to sort files by name in a directory on linux

Tags: c, linux, sorting, directory, kernel

I am learning linux kernel programming and I want to build a program that sorts the files in directory in c programming language just like arrange icons by name option, any suggestion is heartily welcomed.

Comment: Have you built a program yet that reads the names of files in a directory and stores them in memory? If not, your question should leave out sort for now.

Comment: Interesting idea. And what is your question? You see, this is a site that helps solving problems. It is not an "we create ideas for your next project" community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting files implies **iterating over files**.

In kernel space you may do that with `iterate_dir` function. E.g. *listing* files could be performed in this way:

```
// Callback for 'iterate_dir', prints entry.
static int printdir(struct dir_context *ctx, const char *name, int namlen,
       loff_t offset, u64 ino, unsigned int d_type) {
    printk("File: %.*s\n", namelen, name);
}

// usage
struct file* dir = ...; // opened directory
struct dir_context ctx = {.actor = &printdir};
iterate_dir(dir, &ctx);
```

For sorting files, you may store them into array, one by one, and then call `sort()` function. Or you may store files into ordered container (like binary tree), in that case no sorting afterward is needed.